# Audio(.mp3) is not working with react-native-video in android

Tags: audio, react-native, react-native-video

I am facing issue with ***react native-af-video-player*** 0.2.1 and internally it's using react-native-video and by this I am getting crash on while using with audio but same thing is working with video in android.

React native version - 0.59.5
React-Native-Video - 5.0.2, 4.4.2 and also using 4.2.0

IOS - audio & video both are working fine
ANDROID - audio is not working & video is working fine

I am struggling with this issue after upgrading react native version from 0.56.0 to 0.59.5 last three days I am facing the same.

[image: enter code here]

`

Comment: Please try to downgrade exoplayer gradle file into android It might be issue because of android x up-gradation into exoplayer library.